# stop ie suggestions from showing up in webstorm 7 when pressing ctrl+space

Tags: javascript, webstorm

How can i stop api/functions of Internet Explorer from showing up or preferably choose what to show up. I would like only chrome functions to show up as suggestions when i press `ctrl`+ `space` keys.

I went to `file>setting>preference>editor> code completion.`

But there isn't anything that would allow me exclude or choose which one of the browser's api to show..it's just bothersome to see ie icons in every list when i am not even developing for it.

Comment: anyone out there hello?